# What's the correct way to initialize a Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm learning Vue and have seen a lot of different sample apps, documentation and how-to's. There seem to be a number of different ways that people are initializing their components and then mounting them to their app.

My question is why are there so many ways? What's the best practice around this?

For reference I'm doing my build through `npm`, not through an included library in an `HTML` file.

**Option 1**

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function(){
  }
});
```

**Option 2**

```
export default {
  name: "Test",
  data() {
    
  }
};
```

**Option 3**

```
const app = Vue.createApp({})

// Define a new global component called button-counter
app.component('button-counter', {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#components-demo')
```

Option 3 for instance comes from the Vue documentation, but when I initialize an app in that way I get an error that `Vue` doesn't exist.

Hoping to get some clarity for myself and any other beginner that stumbles across this question.

Comment: I edited the tag to show Vue version 3 - that's an important distinction.

Comment: Is it possible you are using the Vue 3 syntax against the Vue 3 API?

Comment: There is no correct way. They are different syntaxes for Vue versions. And in Vue composition API in Vue 3, it even has additional subtle changes in syntax.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1 is the Vue 2 way to create an instance.
- Option 3 is the Vue 3 way.
- Option 2 does not initialize a new Vue instance

The correct way to instantiate is the `createApp({})` function since Vue 3. The new Vue app supported only with Vue 2.

```
`export default {
   name: "Test",
   data() {}
};`
```

The above is one way to create a component named Test. Since Vue3 alternatively you can create a component with `defineComponent({})` function as well

More info -> https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html